# JSON document based storage Flutter(android and iOS)

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-dependencies, storage

I have to download lots of dynamic JSON (around 300) on user input and need to store it to use in next user input. I am not sure which Android storage will fit my requirements.
Shared Preference works but its not ideal to store it in shared preference.

As the key of JSON is also dynamic i can not create column before.
I see MONGO db has document type data structure where document data like JSON can be stored.
But I don't see any equivalent library in Flutter.

Comment: `https://pub.dev/packages/isar` much better than hive

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hive package, it is the fastest in its field.
but you need to convert json to string and store it and convert it to json when you get it.

There is a json_store library or something but I think the logic is the same. hive is much faster so I recommend hive.

It also has an object storage feature that can be useful.

**[Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)**